# Facebook open-graph for iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm trying to implement like in the open-graph API for facebook. I've created a like on the facebook admin page.

I'm logged in on the device with the same account that is the admin for the app on Facebook.
There is a valid token in the application, I have the right permissions.
I've also added the necessary tags on each page that is going to be liked.

This is the code snippet that's trying to post:

```
[appDelegate.facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/app_namespace:like" andParams:md andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:appDelegate];
```

The error message I'm getting is:

```
    code = 2500;
    message = "Unknown path components: /guidepal:like";
    type = OAuthException;
```

What could the problem be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best thing to do is  to follow my answer on this link: [Facebook iOS SDK 3.0, implement like action on a url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12112847/facebook-ios-sdk-3-0-implement-like-action-on-a-url)

It should work perfectly fine on lower facebook sdk:s to if you have saved the access token.